# cannot load locally pretrained model that I deployed via sagemaker notebook

Tags: python, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, torch

Trying to deploy locally pretrained model via sagemaker to make a endpoint and use it
I have been learning AI/ML field lately, and I am such a noob.
Need a help.

## I deployed a model

```
from sagemaker.pytorch import PyTorchModel

pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(model_data='model.tar.gz',
                             role=role,
                             entry_point='inference.py',
                             framework_version="1.11.0",
                             py_version="py38")

predictor = 
pytorch_model.deploy(instance_type='ml.g4dn.xlarge', 
initial_instance_count=1)
```

## and predict data

```
from PIL import Image 
data = Image.open('./samples/inputs/1.jpg')
result = predictor.predict(data)
img = Image.open(result)
img.show()
```

as a result I got an error that I cannot load my model

you can see the error log as well in [here](https://github.com/pytorch/serve/issues/1813)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I have modified my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't make it fully, but loading model is working well now.
It was due to structure of model.tar.gz and inference.py.

my model.tar.gz is structured like below

model.tar.gz
|
|- model.pt
|- code/
| | | - code/inference.py
| | | - code/requirements.txt

This structure is required.

Sometimes, model.pt goes empty file somehow when you make a model.tar.gz, so it is better to check model.pt size is not "0" b4 make tar.gz file.

In addition, if you get wrong with inference.py, such as input_fn, predict_fn, and output_fn, it may occur `Backend worker process died` even if model_fn works properly in my experience.

I am struggling with request_body now.
I keep get request_body as bytearray even if I input JSON file.
my expectation was request_body had to be JSON, but its not.

I will update if I solve this problem.

=======================

Finally, I success inference with endpoint from sagemaker.

The problem was I had to create and input serializer and deserializer class instance when I deploy model SageMaker SDK v2.

you can find serializer and deserializer that offer from sagemaker on [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/v2.109.0/api/inference/serializers.html)

You can make your own class as well.