# How to get the Endpoint for a model built in my machine

Tags: python, deployment, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint, catboost

I have built a model in my machine and want to deploy the model (catboost classifier) in the amazon sagemaker. Not able to get the endpoint of the model. Looking for a code/ process to get the end point. I tried with deploy function, but it is not giving the endpoint, the message is deploy function don't exist for catboostclassifier()

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for “bring your own model” in Sagemaker.

Here is an example with Xgboost :
https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/advanced_functionality/xgboost_bring_your_own_model/xgboost_bring_your_own_model.ipynb

Check the section after “upload pertained model to s3”.

Another blogpost with similar information - again with Xgboost though :(
https://medium.com/geekculture/84af8989d065

1. Upload the trained model object in tar.gz format.
2. Use image_uris.retrieve with `catboost-classification-model` to create a container for catboost
3. create the end point. [This notebook](https://github.com/raja-surya/aws-deployment-1/blob/main/Iris-model-deployment.ipynb) has the detailed steps.

Also this post discusses similar issue :
[cannot load locally pretrained model that I deployed via sagemaker notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73441001/cannot-load-locally-pretrained-model-that-i-deployed-via-sagemaker-notebook)

Comment: In this case, the model is built in SAGEMAKER and deployed as well. In my case I already have the model in my local system, looking for the deployment only at sagemaker.

Comment: This looks close, despite of having the model, in this case it is again creating the model by pulling the data and thereafter exporting the model to S3. This is how you need to proceed if you want to deploy any custom model at sagemaker. Also XGboost is compatable in Sage maker, is catboost too compatable? Not sure and therefore asking these to you.